# Can't get text from JLabel to separate class, modify then set text of JLabel in original class

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm testing code that should from a button action class (that's in a separate .java file) take the text from a JLabel using a getter method in the original class called Testing, modify it and then set the text back to the JLabel of the testing class.

The JLabel is a field of the Testing class, I can GET the text from it into the action class and then I can modify it and set that back to a variable in the Testing class, but when I use label.setText(string var) it doesn't actually change the label on the GUI.

Here's my code for the Testing class which initializes the GUI:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class Testing {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private String temp1;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Testing window = new Testing();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Testing() {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("05656");

        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        label.setBounds(137, 13, 58, 16);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add(label);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(121, 56, 97, 25);
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new TestAction());
    }
    public String getLabel()
    {
        return this.label.getText();
    }
    public void setLabel(String punk)
    {
        System.out.println(punk);
        label.setText(punk + "1");  
    }
}
```

Here's my code for the button action class which does the stuff:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestAction implements ActionListener
{
    Testing test;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        test = new Testing();

        String temp = test.getLabel();

        test.setLabel(temp);    
    }
}
```

I checked around on StackOverflow and found some similar questions like this one: [How to update jLabel or setText from another class in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378611/how-to-update-jlabel-or-settext-from-another-class-in-java)

**This is not the same as the aforementioned question since the solution for that question does not resolve this issue for me**

**If it did, then why would I post this question in the first place, clearly something is different.**

which lead me to trying to pass the JLabel into the button action and then pass it back after modifying the text but that didn't help so I tried updating the JLabel text like this (with a constant):

```
public void setLabel(JLabel punk)
{
    label.setText("yuuh");
}
```

Which does nothing as well, so something is not letting the JLabel be updated even from its own class. I know this is something dumb, but I can't figure out where the breakdown is occurring.

**EDIT:**

I have more information, when I do the label.setText(punk) and then I do System.out.println(label.getText()) it shows that the label text has been changed but it does not change it on the GUI itself.

Comment: Deutro's solution from that link **will** work. You don't pass the JLabel into it's setter method. You pass in either the label, or better the class that holds it in the Listener's constructor. The classic solution, to use an MVC solution, might be over kill at this stage.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean...You say "You don't pass the JLabel into it's setter method" and then say "You pass in either the label...", aren't these contradictory?

Regardless, are you saying that my code should work because Deutro says "your code should work" to that guy and then goes on to write code that does the same thing as my code.

However, my code does not work, the label is not updated with the new text. I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate of that question since that solution does not resolve this, clearly something else is going on.